# How can I get a tag in a view and set some InnerHtml to this tag?

Tags: c#, tags, asp.net-mvc-5, innerhtml, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC 5 View, and I would like to set the InnerHtml of an HTML element.

Here is the HTML code that I would like to add some additional HTML to:

```
<section id="mainContentArea" class="content">
    <!-- Your Page Content Here -->
</section>
```

As a test, I would like to add the following HTML to the above section:

```
<p>Test data</p>
```

So the resulting HTML will be:

```
<section id="mainContentArea" class="content">
    <!-- Your Page Content Here -->
    <p>Test data</p>
</section>
```

This is the code I have coded:

```
@{
    var tag = new TagBuilder("mainContentArea");
    tag.InnerHtml += "<p>Test data</p>";
}
```

The above code does not add any HTML code to the section.

May I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TagBuilder` is used for generating a html element (e.g. `div` or `input` etc), not for getting an element. If your wanting to dynamically add content, you need javascript/jquery

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? This is not how MVC is supposed to be used. Can't you just include a partial there, or render a `@variable` containing the HTML string you want to print?

Comment: The jQuery answer is great! did you want to use jQuery or C#? Did you want to pass data from the Action to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JQuery` to add html dynamically.

```
$("#mainContentArea").html("<p>Test data</p>");
```

However if you have your html is in variable then you can use `@Html.Raw` method.

```
@{string html="<p>Test data</p>";}
   <section id="mainContentArea" class="content">
       @Html.Raw(html)
   </section>
```

Comment: I don't think you will get 'mainContentArea' in Razor code. so you can't add that way.